# PDA have a higher balance then the transferred amount

Tags: solana-program, account, fees

Why does a PDA account have a higher balance than the transferred funds, despite having an initial balance of 0, after I used an anchor program to transfer Solana Lamports from a wallet account to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Anchor initializes program accounts through the init constraint, it will provide sufficient Lamports from the designated payer account to make the program account rent exempt. The additional Lamports that you are observing in the data of the program account are the Lamports necessary to keep it rent-exempt.